# How do I total Column B when Column A is the same in Relational Databases

Tags: php, mysql, relational-database

I have two databases that contain information a Comm_Jobs database that holds all the "jobs" and a Time_Tracker database that keeps track of hours spent on each job. I've got the databases to join but how can I consolidate the results so I have 1 entry for each "job" with the total hours spent on that job.

I am completely lost and cannot wrap my brain around this. Here is the code I have now any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    <?
  include('includes/connectTOdb.php');
 $sql = 'SELECT a.Project, a.Total_Time, b.id, b.Project_Name, c.id, c.First_Name, c.Last_Name
        FROM Time_Tracker a, Comm_Jobs b, Employees c
        WHERE a.Project = b.id';

mysql_select_db('MYDATABASE');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql);
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    echo "Project:{$row['Project_Name']}  <br> ".
         "Total Time: {$row['Total_Time']} <br> ".
         "Employee: {$row['Last_Name']}, {$row['First_Name']} <br> <br>".
         "--------------------------------<br><br>";
} 
echo "Fetched data successfully\n";
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried `GROUP BY Comm_Jobs`? Past that, you're looking at a JOIN like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3320863/get-sum-in-group-by-with-join-using-mysql

Comment: How is `Employees` table related to other tables? Consider to show table schemas and desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `JOIN` and `GROUP BY` to properly `SUM()` the field you want:

```sql
SELECT SUM(a.Total_Time) as Time_Sum, b.Project_Name
FROM Time_Tracker a
JOIN Comm_Jobs b ON a.Project = b.id
GROUP BY a.Project;
```

Comment: Thanks, That helped... but now I'm not getting accurate totals, and some "Jobs" are missing from the list. not sure why this would happen.

Comment: Figured out my issues, didn't change the echo.